# Crystal Reports 2008 changing text output color based on datetime value

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I'm new at Crystal Reports, & trying to write a formula in Crystal Reports 2008 that will produce red text if a specific datetime field is null, and black text if it is not null.  CR 2008 does not have a formula button next to the font color picker when formatting the existing text field, so I'm trying the following formula to generate the text, but I can't seem get the crRed & crBlack color values to input properly:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global stringVar sText;

IF IsNULL({CONTACT.CSS_HR_DESK_OFFICE_ASSIGNED})
THEN sText:=("TEXT")
ELSE sText:=("TEST");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI, I figured out a workaround for this using the Highlighting Expert, but if there's a way to do it in formula I'd still love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

right click on the field
format field
fonttab
click the formula editor for color

```
if isnull({field}) then red
else 
black
```

but a null field wont display text to change to red :)